# Apparent errer when installing plugin

Tags: plugins, errors, activation

I have been working on my first plugin (call is myplugin).  The path to the plugin code is wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php.  The myplugin.php file is essentially as follows:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/*
 * Plugin Name:  My Plugin
 */

function my_plugin_activation() {
    global $wpdb;
    // SQL code to insert custom database tables
    // using CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename....
}

function my_plugin_deactivation() {   
    // SQL code to update table on deactivation
}

function my_plugin_uninstall() {
    global $wpdb;
    // SQL code to remove custom database tables
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activation');
register_deactivaction_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_deactivation');
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_uninstall');
?>
```

When I activate the above plugin code the tables are created successfully by the my_plugin_activation routine, the plugin is activated (I get a Deactivate link when if finishes activating), yet the following messages are displayed at the top of the Plugins screen:

```
Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare my_plugin_activaction() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\deve1wp\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\myplugin.php: 15) in C:\xampp\htdocs\deve1wp\wp-content\plugins\myplugin\myplugin.php on line 198
```

Line 15 is the actual function definition.  Line 198 is the line where I register the activation hook.

What gives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it happen if the functions don't do anything, i.e. they are as you posted them in this question?

Comment: plugin activation is a weird thing, WordPress has to do it in such a way as to not take everything down if a plugin activation triggers a fatal error, and as such, I've read reports that any error manifests itself as a "cannot redeclare" error despite that not actually being the case. make sure your activation and deactivation code outside of the activation/deactivation context has no errors. also have a look at the `active_plugins` option to make sure your plugin isn't already in that list when it's actually deactivated.

Comment: You code above works fine (minus typo).  I just tried it.  IMO, you have something else that is interferring.  Probably some error within the code that you are not showing.

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking @Milo

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I didn't realize this was a generic message for pretty much all errors. I stripped everything out of the activation routine (similar to above) and ran it... got no errors. Started adding "stuff" back. And it appears a call to flush() at the end of the activation function trying to force the /wp-content/debug.log to be flushed to disk was triggering the error.

Thanks to everyone here that helped!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on this line:

```
register_deactivaction_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_deactivation');
```

It should be:

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_deactivation');
```

Comment: Thanks.  The typo is only in the sample above.  I spelled everything correctly in my actual plugin code.  So that is not the root issue.

The error message makes me think that it sees the register_*_hook as trying to redeclare the functions being attached to those hooks.  I have found tons of instances of people complaining about this online, but no real solutions posted.

Comment: Are you trying this with a fresh install of WP, and with what version of PHP? The above works for me (less the typo of course) with WP 4.0, PHP 5.6.2. You might also see if XAMPP might be throwing things off.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm running a new install of WordPress 4.0, PHP 5.5.15, and Twenty Fourteen theme.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly calling the plugin path? As in something like: WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/myplugin/myplugin.php'

Comment: Actually I did try:

register_activation_hook( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/myplugin/myplugin.php', 'my_plugin_activation');

But got the same error.

I do have the following in my wp-config.php:

define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

I think one of these causes additional PHP errors to be logged that wouldn't normally be logged.  I have not tried running it with these set to false.

Comment: I think I found the problem.  I didn't realize this was a generic message for pretty much all errors.

I stripped everything out of the activation routine (similar to above) and ran... got no errors.  Started adding "stuff" back.  And it  appears a call to flush() at the end trying to force the /wp-content/debug.log to be flushed to disk was triggering the error.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Bet you're already going to do this, but probably a good to idea to explain that in answer here for posterity.